# Changing LaF based on OS

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, ide, look-and-feel

Im building a GUI in Netbeans, it looks good in the designer but when I run the program it looks pretty rubbish. Im using a Mac and so I feel that it would look better using the Mac OS LAF but then when I run it on Windows, what will happen? Is a Windows system able to use the Mac LAF and vice-versa?

I dont usually mind the Ocean/Metal LAF but it looks better on Windows than it does on Mac, is there a way to set a theme as a fallback? Or to change depending on the system its running on?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `UIManager.setLookAndFeel(String className)` Loads the `LookAndFeel` specified by the given class name:`className`, using the current **thread's** context class loader.

To set look and feel of your *current* system, make use of `UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName()`: Returns the name of the `LookAndFeel` class that implements the native system look and feel if there is one, otherwise the name of the default cross platform `LookAndFeel` class.

```
UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
```

put this code before you create instance of your application window: `JFrame` or any such Top-level Container.